# Error with Hibernate HQL - unexpected token:

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hql

```
***import org.hibernate.Query;***

String hql = "FROM :className WHERE userCreate like ':userName'";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("className", className);
query.setParameter("userName", userName);
List<Node> result = query.list();
```

And have an error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 6 [FROM :className WHERE userCreate like ':userName']
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at com.SDC.DAO.DAOFileAndFolderService.findUserCreteFileOrFolder(DAOFileAndFolderService.java:36)
at com.SDC.View.Main.main(Main.java:57)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.SDC.View.Main.main(Main.java:58)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use named parameters for Hibernate queries. You can get around this by manually appending the name of the table into your hql string. Your code would look instead like this:

```
String hql = "FROM " + className + " WHERE userCreate like ':userName'";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("userName", userName);
List<Node> result = query.list();
```

Comment: yup. tks for your answer